# Why is subtyping preserved in this example without using the out keyword?

Tags: kotlin, oop, generics, collections, covariance

Here a have a generic type, but I don't understand why even though I didn't made the type T covariant, I can add subclasses of Player to my generics class and function which has an upper bound T: Player; so why is the subtyping preserved without using the out keyword; and because of this I can - wrongly- add a BaseballPlayer and GamesPlayer to a football team. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUDsN.png)

```
class Team<T : Player>(val name: String, private val players: MutableList<T>) {
  fun addPlayers(player: T) {
    if (players.contains(player)) {
      println("Player: ${(player as Player).name} is already in the team.")
    } else {
      players.add(player)
      println("Player: {(player as Player).name} was added to the team.")
    }
  }
}

open class Player(open val name: String)

data class FootballPlayer(override val name: String) : Player(name)
data class BaseballPlayer(override val name: String) : Player(name)
data class GamesPlayer(override val name: String) : Player(name)

val footballTeam = Team<Player>(
  "Football Team",
  mutableListOf(FootballPlayer("Player 1"), FootballPlayer("Player 2"))
)

val baseballPlayer = BaseballPlayer("Baseball Player")
val footballPlayer = FootballPlayer("Football Player")
val gamesPlayer = GamesPlayer("Games Player")

footballTeam.addPlayers(baseballPlayer)
footballTeam.addPlayers(footballPlayer)
footballTeam.addPlayers(gamesPlayer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mutable list you defined on this line:

```
mutableListOf(FootballPlayer("Player 1"), FootballPlayer("Player 2"))
```

is not a `MutableList<FootballPlayer>`. It is a `MutableList<Player>`, since you didn't specify its type, so the compiler used type inference to assume you want a `MutableList<Player>` to fit the constructor argument for your `Team<Player>` constructor.

So, it is valid to put any kind of `Player` into a `MutableList<Player>`, since it can only ever return items of type `Player`. It's still type safe.

If you had been explicit about the type, it would have been a compile error:

```
val footballTeam = Team<Player>(
  "Football Team",
  mutableListOf<FootballPlayer>(FootballPlayer("Player 1"), FootballPlayer("Player 2"))
  //error, expected MutableList<Player>
)
```

Or if you had omitted the type from the Team constructor, it would have assumed you wanted a `Team<FootballPlayer>` and you would have had an error when trying to add other types of player:

```
val footballTeam = Team(
  "Football Team",
  mutableListOf(FootballPlayer("Player 1"), FootballPlayer("Player 2"))
)
// ^^ is a Team<FootballPlayer> because of type inferrence.

footballTeam.addPlayers(BaseballPlayer("Foo")) // error, expected FootballPlayer
```

Comment: Thank you! But if I change to: val footballTeam = Team<Player>(mutableListOf<FootballPlayer("Player 1"); I don't get an error, because FootballPlayer is a subclass of Player. So, I can't ilustrate covariance because of this.

Comment: The error occurs for me: https://pl.kotl.in/mg6vbXrmd Make sure you have no typos.

Comment: Now is working - Thank you for your help! But now I wonder how can I show using this code, how covariance and contravariance works? With this code: https://pl.kotl.in/vVlEZW9TR

Comment: Are you just trying to understand different types of variance? A covariant version of your team could not allow you to add players, and a contravariant version of your team could not allow you see which players are in the team.